# How to copy existing column and insert it into datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I currently have a datagrid that contains a unique context menu for each column.. sample xaml is as follows:

```
  <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource default_columnHeaderMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person" Binding="{Binding Path=PersonID}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignedCellStyle}" />
```

....

Inside the context menu, I have an item called "Insert column" which then contains a list of columns like so:

```
       <ContextMenu  x:Key="default_columnHeaderMenu" Name="defaultColumnHeaderMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Insert Column" >
                <MenuItem Header="Person ID" Click="addColumn"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Health" />
                <MenuItem Header="Person Description" />
                <MenuItem Header="Person Age" />
```

.....

MY question is, using the column header context menus, what is the easiest way to add or duplicate these columns into my data grid ? (I'm not looking for a brand new, empty column, but some kind of "copy" of an already exiting column w/ the same data, etc.)

Using DataGrid.Columns, is there a way to some how find an index of a column based on the header name ?

Thanks for any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your columns as non-shared resources:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Key="PersonColumn" x:Shared="False" Header="Person" Binding="{Binding Path=PersonID}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignedCellStyle}" />
```

Then in the menu item event you can retrieve it and add it to the DataGrid:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var col = FindResource("PersonColumn") as DataGridTemplateColumn;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though it looks like I am unable to have a "Key" property for my columns.

Comment: I noted that you should define it as a resource, i.e. in some resource dictionary, e.g. `<Window.Resources><!-- Here --></Window.Resources>` [MSDN on Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to achieve the results. Though one more question, are there any limitations to a "non-shared" resource in terms of binding to data ? If I was to add a new "Person" column would that column still have the same two-way binding data as the original ?

Comment: It would not have the same binding but an identical one i suppose.